# Can data saved on the iPhone by an App using writeToFile be included in the results of a Spotlight search?

Tags: ios, iphone, search, writetofile, spotlight

An application I am designing will be used to sync data between the iPhone and a database.  I am writing the data on the iPhone using 'writeToFile' and similar methods, and syncing it periodically with the database.  Is there any way I can make this data appear in the Spotlight search utility on the iPhone?

Comment: Pretty sure this is reserved exclusively for system-managed databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  When you write to a file, that file is written into your apps "sandbox".  Only your app and no other part of the device can access the contents of your sandbox.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected there might be some sort of quarantined storage for app data. I've seen plenty of answers to this question simply stating that Spotlight cannot search within apps, I'm glad there's a more in-depth answer.